# Find languages L1 and L2, neither of which contains the other, such that (L1* ∪ L2*) = (L1 ∪ L2)*.

Tags: proof-writing, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm trying solve this question in several ways, but only textbook has not helped me alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a one-symbol alphabet $\Sigma = \{a\}$, let

$$
\begin{align}
L_1 &= \{a^{2n+1} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \\
L_2 &= \{a^{2n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \text{.} \\
\end{align}
$$

Then $L_1 \nsubseteq L_2$ and $L_1 \nsubseteq L_1$, in fact $L_1 \cap L_2 = \emptyset$.

We also have $L_1^{*} = \Sigma^{*}$, and $L_2^{*} = L_2$.

So: 
$$
L_1^{*} \cup L_2^{*} = \Sigma^{*} \text{.}
$$
Clearly, $L_1 \cup L_2 =  \Sigma^{*}$, so:
$$
(L_1 \cup L_2)^{*} =  \Sigma^{*} \text{.}
$$

Comment: You could just let L1={a} and L2={aa}.

Comment: @MJO Those work. {a}, {aa}  and the $L_1, L_2$ I used have the same closures respectively. In a sense, {a} and {aa} are as small as can be, while  $L_1, L_2$ are infinite and complementary.